# Proving Center of Modular Group

Tags: number-theory

The center of a group G is defined by
ZG ={z∈G:gz=zg for all g∈G}.
Prove that the center of the modular group consists of two elements ±I, where I is the 2 × 2 identity matrix.

I attempted to prove this by solving a system of equations obtained following matrix multiplication of matrix $ 
   M=
  \left[ {\begin{array}{cc}
   a & b \\
   c & d \\
  \end{array} } \right]
$ where ad - bc = 1 with some matrix X, such that MX = XM, but was not getting anywhere. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

If $M = \left(\begin{smallmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{smallmatrix}\right)$ commutes with all elements $2 \times 2$ matrices with unit determinant, then in particular
$$
\left(\begin{matrix} -b & a \\ -d & c \end{matrix}\right) = 
\left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{matrix}\right)
= \left(\begin{matrix} c & d \\ -a & -b \end{matrix}\right).
$$
This shows $c=-b$ and $a=d$. Now apply the same idea using the matrix $\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{smallmatrix}\right)$, you should find $b=0$, and then $ad-bc=a^2+b^2 = a^2=1$.